# php-win.exe - The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I am on a Windows 7, 64 bits.
I have installed WampServer 3.0.6 x64 (last version).
I have installed the [Visual C++ 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) x64 (last version too).
Everything went successfully !

But i still have the same error when I try to run WampServer :

> php-win.exe - Application Error
>
> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b). Click OK to close the application.

I tried everything, still gets this same error.

Comment: Check that you have installed ALL the MSVC C/C++ runtime libraries required. They are all mentioned in the install. But if you missed them, see http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @RiggsFolly point out in comment, I had to install all the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime librairies :

- **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) :** [Visual C++ 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)
- **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 :** [Visual C++ 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)
- **Update for Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package :** [Visual C++ 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032938/update-for-visual-c-2013-redistributable-package)
- **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 :** [Visual C++ 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840)

Many more links and fix to different problems can be found in this link (i'm not affiliated) http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295.

Answer (score 4):

Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribute package required or compatible for the software.

Answer (score 3):

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b). Click OK to close the application.

If you have the above error, then try one of solutions below

1. Install Microsoft Visual C++ run time libraries

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685

2. Check if Port 80 is free, if not the change the Listener in httpd.conf file to some other port

How to Open httpd.conf - Click on WAMP in tray- Click Apache - Click http.conf a file will be opened in notepad/notepad++

Listen 0.0.0.0:80        - Change 80 to 8080 or anything other port

Listen [::0]:80

Server Name localhost:80 - Change to 8080

You can also check in Task Manager if Port 80 is really being used by following below steps

Go to Task Manager - View Menu - Columns- Check Mark (PID)
Go to Process Tab - Show all process and sort by PID and you can see if port 80 is really being used.

3. Before starting installation of WAMP, disable IIS and quit Skype and other unwanted applications.

The above solutions should solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, You need to install more files about Microsoft Visual C++ runtime libraries.
[Checks VC++ packages installed](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe)
And you will find all the packages on http://wampserver.aviatechno.net

This problem was fixed for me this way. Thanks to the [forum.wampserver](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,149565)