# php-win.exe - The application was unable to start correctly

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I install wamp server correctly but when I open this server its shows that php-win.exe application error:

> The Application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)..

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php-win.exe - The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513898/php-win-exe-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc00007b)

Comment: ^ Found the above as the second result on Google when I simply search on the error message. Just as a hint for next time.

Comment: no. i'm download it from another website as same version. Because I already downloaded it many times, that's why they don't want to give it free... I already anstall MSVC C++ runtime, 2008, 2010, 2012 and 2015.. Please give me a suggestion to fix this problem...

Comment: use Docker ;-) trust me, having a dev environment that uses a linux vm is way better. if you install it, i'll link you to my config files, and within a couple of commands you will have a fully working LAMP stack

Comment: _"Because I already downloaded it many times, that's why they don't want to give it free"_ - Why not download it from a proper site, then? What's so special about their version?

Comment: It's already done. Now give me a suggestion How to solved this error..